# Looking for Autodesk Sketchbook Copic edition app - or similar with Copic features

Tags: web-apps

I'm trying to find recommendations for where I can access drawing apps with *Copic* colour markers.

My boyfriend had downloaded the autodesk sketchbook copic edition for free from the app store a while back but bought a new computer and the app seems to be gone from the app store now.

Does anyone know about software apps with Copic features specifically?

Comment: You would be better off asking for recommendations of a suitable alternative, possibly gratis, with what features you are specifically looking for, rather than asking for a possibly illegal or infected copy.

Comment: Thanks Steve! Yes, I did try to persuade him of that but he is desperate to get a copy so I relented, and asked!

Comment: For future reference, we found the reason. The free app has been discontinued and they have incorporated the Copic features into a new app, but with I think 40 out of the 72 colours available as part of its free version. My boyf tells me that the Copic colours are pretty unique so he is happy to have these for now.

Comment: Your question was nominated to be re-opened (due to your latest edit). However, it still lacks details, as Steve already pointed out in his comment. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) (and [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185)), then [edit] your questions to include required details (such as features you need, and what the software must be capable of). Thanks!

Comment: No more details that I can add I'm afraid. In my edit I asked for recommendations for software that include Copic features, i.e. colour palette, as there might have been others. That's it I'm afraid, I'll have to leave it there! thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a download available, as a **trial edition**, at http://copic.jp/en/sketchbook-ce.html

But for a full 3D modelling too that is Free, can do animation, rendering and lighting, (plus has a lot more than 72 colours), take a look at [Blender](https://www.blender.org/), there are even full & short movies that have been produced with it, e.g. [Project London](http://projectlondonmovie.com/) & [Big Bucks Bunny](https://peach.blender.org/).

Comment: Thanks Steve, but is the Mac download working for you? For me it is redirecting to what seems to be the Japanese app store, and then it just seems to revert to default 'top sites' page.

Comment: My Japanese is non-existent and I don't have a Mac

Comment: Don't worry, the Japanese version doesn't even load, except for a moment. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: Seriously - give blender a try!

Comment: Copic have their own colour palette. And it is for 2D drawing.